# PhoneGap eu posso criar um app e comercializar ele?

Tags: apache-cordova

Eu posso não comercializar, mas publicar ele na play store, e colocar comerciais e ganha sobre o app sem ter penalidade?

Tem alguma licença que diz que não pode comercializar?

Tem que pagar o phonegap para poder publica-lo ou posso ficar tranquilo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode comercializar, monetizar, distribuir gratuitamente ou mesmo como open source ou ambos combinados sem o dever de onerar a desenvolvedora da IDE.

> Q: HOW MUCH DOES PHONEGAP COST?
>
> A: PhoneGap is an open source implementation of open standards and is
>   FREE. That means developers and companies can use PhoneGap for mobile
>   applications that are free, commercial, open source, or any
>   combination of these.

fonte: http://phonegap.com/about/faq/

Comment: Muito Obrigado!